# Getting hostname using sqlmap

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection, penetration-testing, sqlmap

There is a website `abc.com` which is vulnerable to SQL injection, I have verified this via `sqlmap` , So i got the username and password after this

```
https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage
```

but I noticed that database is running on oracle, I want to get the host so i can connect to the database from Oracle client.

--hostname returns `abc.com` , how can I get the actual DB hostname so i can connect via Oracle client using SQLMAP.

**when I did port scan of abc.com only 40 and 443 are open.**

P.S This is only for learning purpose

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can `SELECT` on the `ORACLE` database proper tables, This should do the trick:

```
SELECT host_name from v$instance
```

If you want more information on how to connect, then you should try

```
SELECT type , value FROM v$listener_network
```

It will give you the database network name, and a connection string from `localhost`.

Comment: what is the database for v$instance ? (sorry I have been to mysql for longer time)

Comment: It is for an Oracle Database. I made a typo, it is `HOST_NAME`, not `HOSTNAME`

Comment: this returns abc.com (which was actually returned by sqlmap too)

Comment: Then querying `v$listener_network` might be helpfull.

Comment: Then I have no more clue. You might access the database on port 40 with a connection string like this one: `(ADDRESS=(HOST=abc.com)(PROTOCOL=tcp)(PORT=40))`, and it is also possible that the database can only be accessed locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to the database you can simply use the --sqlmap-shell that make a prompt for an interactive sqlmap shell.

```
sqlmap -u abc.com --sqlmap-shell
```

But also if you want the current database you can use the --current-db option.

```
 sqlmap -u abc.com --current-db
```